# Soft question: Is field theory unfathomable? (Aluffi, Algebra Chapter 0)

Tags: field-theory, soft-question

In *Allufi, Algebra Chapter 0*, in the 7th Chapter, the author says

> The minuscle amount of algebra we have developed thus far allows us to
> scratch the surface of the **unfathomable** subject of **field theory**

seemingly hinting that field theory is very complex and hard to understand. However, recently when talking to a friend, they disagreed saying field theory is quite simple: according to them, to study a field extension, you separate it into transcendental and algebraic parts, and separate the latter into separable and non-separable parts: for the separable parts use Galois theory, and the non-separable parts are just given by adjoining p-th roots of elements.

So why does Aluffi call field theory unfathomable? Is there more depth to this?

Comment: This is very vague, as is the original quote.  It all depends on what you mean by "field theory".   If the theory of finite extensions of $\mathbb Q$ includes all of Algebraic Number Theory, say, then I'd say that was pretty complex already.

Comment: It's a bit like saying "$\mathbb{Z}$ is a very complex object". It depends what you ask about it. If you want to describe its elements, well, it's the integers, so... yeah, that's fine. But if you want to solve all diophantine equations, this is a hopelessly complicated subject that humanity will never even vaguely scratch the surface of.

Comment: Field theory is very complicated (only think of the galois theory), but not unfathomable ! With this argument, I could also claim that the proof for Dirichlet's theorem about the primes in arithmetic progression is "unfathomable" because I never was able to understand it.

Comment: Certainly field theory is unfathom**ed**, because it is an active theory of research; your friend is wrong in that regard. But is the author right that field theory is unfathom**able**? Well, it's hard to know isn't it? Can we predict the future and tell whether field theory will ever be completely fathom**ed**? I think we should just grant the author poetic license in this regard.

Comment: Here is an example of a very basic question in field theory: how can I describe the cyclic extensions (of order $n$, say) of a field $K$ when it does not have primitive $n$th roots of unity? This is honestly a very simple and natural question. It is so incredibly difficult that there is a fair chance it remains forever unanswered.

Comment: What have open problems to do with whether a topic is unfathomed ? The theory of prime numbers is full of open conjectures, but I would not say it is unfathomed yet. With this argument, almost every topic would be yet unfathomed.

Comment: @Peter Precisely. Which is to say, the word does not mean much in itself.

Comment: I'd say Galois theory at first is simple an elegant, but then more and more topics and problems add by themselves and it becomes very deep.

Answer (score 1):

I will answer you question in two aspects.

Firstly, as a student, the theory itself it was relatively fine to me. I mean, if the course is really heavy on the field theory, it will be really a mess. All kinds of extension and all kinds of theorems of these extensions will just make you forget everything. But the idea is simple, once you mind is clear (like after you finish the course, and sometime in the future you need to review it again), it is clear.

For me, when I took the graduate field theory course (sometimes it is the second algebra course or the first algebra course, depending on the school), the hardest part is to compute the Galois group for some really weird extension.

See this:
[The Galois group of $x^{4}-a$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ where $a$ is any integer $\neq 0$, $\neq \pm 1$ and is square free.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2726135/the-galois-group-of-x4-a-over-mathbbq-where-a-is-any-integer-neq-0)

[Find the Galois group of $x^{4}-t$ over $\mathbb{R}(t)$, where $t$ is transcendental over the complex number $\mathbb{C}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2727240/find-the-galois-group-of-x4-t-over-mathbbrt-where-t-is-transcende)

And just think about how you will find the splitting field and the Galois group of the polynomials of $x^{77}-1$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta^{28})$ where $\zeta$ is a $77^{th}-$root of unity.

Especially when you have a professor that works on number theory, this kind of things will make you nuts. I really like some schools' algebra course that do not focus too much on the field theory (instead they focus on Ring and module, which are much more essential for students who want to work on algebraic geometry), because it really is not motivated for a student. You just could not see the point of computing all these Galois group, and then you still could not read any paper, right? This destroys the motivation.

---

To generally reply your question, the point of field theory being hard is that as long as you work on anything that relates to number theory, you have to understand it completely, and the field theory extends to many other branches of Mathematics.

Let us take affine height function as an example. It can be defined in the following way $$h(\alpha):=\dfrac{1}{[K:\mathbb{Q}]}\sum_{v}n_{v}\log\max(|\alpha|_{v},1),$$ where $n_{v}$ is the local degree, $K\subset\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ a number field, and $\alpha\in K$ algebraic, and your summation $v$ is summing over all places in $M_{K}$. Note that here, the places are over $K$.

On the other hand, you can also define it as $$h(\alpha):=\dfrac{1}{d}\sum_{v}\sum_{\alpha'}\log\max(|\alpha'|_{v},1),$$ where $d$ is the degree of the minimum polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, but now, the summation over $v$ are summing over all the places of $M_{\mathbb{Q}}$, and $\alpha'$ are the conjugates of $\alpha$ on the Galois orbit.

So, why these two things are the same? There are many books using a whole lot chapter to give you the background to simply just understand this. And as you will see you must understand the field theory completely, and then you need to apply the field theory to all these algebraic number theory stuff.

The theory itself is never that difficult, and all the Galois theory, separable, inseparable, normal extension, all these kinds of stuff, have been studied for a long while, and they appear in your PhD introductory course, right? Because they only give you background. But completely understanding them, knowing how to apply them in a slightly different subject, are indeed hard.

Well. I don't know if this answers your question, but I cannot help post such an answer.